# how to SUBSTRING such a data into to two columns, longitude and latitude column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Location(32.747156999999994 -26.994015989999998)
Location(32.06873196 -27.429944579999997)
Location(32.271466 -27.040925)
Location(32.271466 -27.040925)
Location(32.183663 -28.422186)
Location(32.753835 -26.989512)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `LOCATION`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `CASE` , `SUBSTRING()` and `CHARINDEX()` :

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',Location)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Location,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Location)-1) END Longitute
        ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',Location)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Location,CHARINDEX(' ',Location)+1,len(Location))  END Latitude
FROM Locations
```

if the data located like 'Location(32.753835 -26.989512)' you can simply `REPLACE` 'Location(' and ')'

```
SELECT   REPLACE(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',Location)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Location,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Location)-1) END,'Location(','') Longitute
        ,REPLACE(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',Location)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(Location,CHARINDEX(' ',Location)+1,len(Location)) END,')','') Latitude
FROM Locations
```

Answer (score 1):

A very pragmatic approach...

Using some simple string-replacements we can create a SQL-Statement dynamically and use `EXEC()` to execute it:

```
DECLARE @YourData NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'Location(32.747156999999994 -26.994015989999998)
Location(32.06873196 -27.429944579999997)
Location(32.271466 -27.040925)
Location(32.271466 -27.040925)
Location(32.183663 -28.422186)
Location(32.753835 -26.989512)';

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'SELECT * FROM (VALUES' + 
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourData,'Location',','),' ',','),2,100000) + 
') tbl(Long,Lat);';

EXEC(@stmt);
```

The statement created looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 VALUES(32.747156999999994,-26.994015989999998)
      ,(32.06873196,-27.429944579999997)
      ,(32.271466,-27.040925)
      ,(32.271466,-27.040925)
      ,(32.183663,-28.422186)
      ,(32.753835,-26.989512)
) tbl(Long,Lat);
```

The result

```
Long                Lat
32.747156999999994  -26.994015989999998
32.068731960000000  -27.429944579999997
32.271466000000000  -27.040925000000000
32.271466000000000  -27.040925000000000
32.183663000000000  -28.422186000000000
32.753835000000000  -26.989512000000000
```

Comment: +1 for creativity and (likely) best performance. I don't know  how well this solution scales out. It would be a fun test to see at what point (how many rows) the dynamic SQL statement becomes too big. 

On a funny side note: 100,000 characters long for substring - that's one looooong coordinate ;)

Comment: @AlanBurstein , it might be better to use STUFF() to get rid of the leading comma. Or simply to add (0, 0) to the literal and let the comma in place... Btw, the 100000 is targeting the whole string in one piece...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SUBSTRING` method, where you can set from what point you want to create a new string:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = '32.747156999999994 -26.994015989999998'
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(' ', @string) +1, 20)
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@string, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @string) +1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
-26.994015989999998
32.747156999999994
```

Comment: The code is a bit more complicated if the coordinate value is stored as `Location(lat,lon)`

Comment: @Stavr00 do you mean if location would be stored in two fields?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is in string format, you can use string index function to identify the location of space and split on that basis:

```
select LocV,substr(LocV,0,instr(locV,' ')) as Longitute,substr(LocV,instr(LocV,' ')+1,length(LocV)) as Latitude from loc
```

Here is demo link :[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37fc4e/11/0)